# Jquery validation form: if an input field is empty do something, if not, do something else. Do it for each input

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input, each

I have this function that returns true only if all input fields are not empty.
If the input field is empty, the returned value is "empty field", if is not empty the text "ok" appears.

Here u are the Jquery:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#btnSubmit').on('click',isEveryInputEmpty); 
    });


    function isEveryInputEmpty() {
    var failCount = ($('#formId input').length)-1; 
    var control = 1;

    $('#formId input').each(function() {

        var txTarget=$('#formId #txTargetResult' + control);

        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            txTarget.text('empty field');
            failCount++;
            control++;
        }else if($(this).val() != '') {
            txTarget.text('ok');
            failCount--;
            control++;        
        }
    });

    if(failCount > 0){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the html too:

```
<head>        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="row col-md-offset-2 col-md-12">
                <h1>Form</h1>
            </header>

            <form action="file.php" method="get" id="formId">

                <div class="row">             
                        <input type="text" id="someId" placeholder="1">
                        <div class="target col-md-5" id="txTargetResult1">
                        </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="row">             
                        <input type="text" id="someId" placeholder="2">
                        <div class="target col-md-5" id="txTargetResult2">
                        </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="row">             
                        <input type="text" id="someId" placeholder="3">
                        <div class="target col-md-5" id="txTargetResult3">
                        </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="row">             
                        <input type="text" id="someId" placeholder="4">
                        <div class="target col-md-5" id="txTargetResult4">
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>


        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="validationcontrol.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works, but to start the function I need to manually name every #txTargetResult number, as u can see in the html.
I would like to find a more dynamic way, without naming the html div.

Comment: can you show us your HTML please? the code seems like it should work but to verify it, we need to see the DOM it is modifying

Answer (score 1):

You are looping trough all you tagets in the foreach loop, means on each loop step you are adressing a element.

Given that you can easily select your elements by choosing `this`!

You can replace your `control` with `$(this).attr("id")`, which gets you the id of the current element you are iterating over.

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="one" class="elementWithID">One</div>
<div id="two" class="elementWithID">Two</div>
<div id="three" class="elementWithID">Three</div>

<!-- For test purposes, the data is written in this div -->

<div id="results"></div>
```

js Code:

```
// Get all elements with class elementWithID

var elementsWithID = $(".elementWithID");

// Loop trough all these elements

$.each(elementsWithID,function(){

        // Append the id attribute of a element to the results div
    $("#results").append($(this).attr("id"));       

});
```

Comment: Please could you go a little bit more deeper? If I change the  var txTarget=$('#formId #txTargetResult' + control); in  var txTarget=$(this).attr("#txTargetResult"); the script doesn't work.

Comment: Oh yeah, the id is a fix string, the `attr()` method gets or sets an DOM attribute, if you only pass one parameter, like here "id" it gets the attribute it, if you e.g. use `attr("id","newId")` it sets this element's attibute to "newId". Check out my updated answer, i included example code for you to orientate yourself

Comment: You can check the life example on this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wocanihapu/edit?html,js,console,output). Your problem should now be solved.

Comment: Good this helped me to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

try;

```
var txTarget = $(this).closest(".target");
```

Now you may remove all those `id="txTargetResult1"`, `id="txTargetResult2"` etc

**EDIT**

I recommend you to use `txTarget.html('');` instead of `txTarget.text('');`

Give it a try and see if this works

Comment: the script works in this way, but the text() function doesn't when apply it to the txTarget variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Validation Plugin

1. It is dynamic and client side.
2. Validation apply on every form field.

[Refrence link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Hope this help.

Comment: I really don't like use too much plugins for this kind of things, i prefer manage by myself a slight amount of code. But thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

The solution is an half way between the answer of Tarekis and Blasteralfred.
Using the next() I get the result I was looking for.

```
function isEveryInputEmpty() {
    var failCount = ($('#formId input').length)-1; 

    $('#formId input').each(function() {
        var txTarget = $(this).next(".target");

        if($(this).val() === '') {
            txTarget.text('empty field');
            failCount++;

        }else if($(this).val() != '') {
            txTarget.text('ok');
            failCount--;      
        }
    });

    if(failCount > 0){
        return false;
    }
}
```